# Using a C++ API in Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, wrapper

I'm, currently developing a game in Java and want to publish it on Steam when it's finished.
Their website says the Steam API was written in C++, and when I e-mailed them to ask whether there is a way to use the API in Java, they told me I had to write a wrapper for this

My question is: How do I write such a wrapper, or did someone else write this previously and made it available for downloading?

Comment: Native is the keyword for which you are looking , search for how to call native methods in java and you will be done :)

Answer (score 3):

The key technology you're looking for is the [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to automatically generate the glue code (JNI).

You need the C++ header files and can create java packages and classes
which you can use in you project.
See [Swig and Java](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java) for details.